# What should I do when the carrier unilaterally canceled my booking?

Tags: air-travel, mexico, cancellations

I booked a flight couple weeks ago, taking off tomorrow. Today I tried to get a boarding pass but their app says that my booking was somehow canceled (I didn't do that), the money is returned to my credit card. The company in question is Volaris.
What do you think I should do in this case? Try to put some pressure on them, or just give up and get a new ticket? (They cost x3 more when buying today, though).
UPD  I finally got a reply from their helpdesk and they insist that there was a problem with the payment, and that's why they canceled my booking. However, I didn't get any notifications about that "payment problem" or the booking cancelation.

Comment: If you really didn’t get any notification of the cancellation then why wouldn’t you contact them to complain? https://cms.volaris.com/globalassets/pdfs/eng/customerserviceplan.pdf

Comment: @Traveller their helpdesk is quite slow but I finally got a reply and they insist that there was a problem with the payment, and that's why they canceled my booking. However, I didn't get any notifications about that "payment problem" or the cancelation.

Comment: Does your credit card issuer report that the original credit card charge went through when you bought the ticket? Has the charge been reversed since then?

Comment: @David supports Monica my online banking shows that the charge went through and was reversed.

Comment: I'd ask the credit card issuer who caused the reversal. With that info, you may have something factual to present to the airline.

Comment: @David supports Monica I will. However, isn't the carrier obliged to at least notify customers about such events?

Comment: Morally: yes, the carrier should do so. Legally: the answer depends on the carrier's Terms and Conditions of Carriage.

Comment: We had a similar problem with the same carrier - booked a friend on a flight, everything worked, payment successful, but when he got to the airport and showed all the info they told him that the online booking wasn't valid.  They made him pay cash at the airport for a new ticket.  We had booked through the airline's website, and were able to get a refund to CC from them a week or so later.  However, that experience (and now yours) has put me off using them